# How to distinct column using MS SQL if u can't use it in SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, distinct

this is my code

```
 select pd.postFilial as postoffice,
        cr.number as region,
        coalesce(cd.number, cr.number) as district,
        c.number as city,
        pd.postIndex as postcode,
        pd.name as name,
        lf.reason as lock_reason
 from pn_district pd
 inner join cd_city c on c.NUMBER = pd.cityDistrict
 left join pn_lockfilial lf with (nolock) on lf.id_postfilial = pd.postFilial
 left join cd_region cd  on cd.number = c.parent_id
 left join cd_region cr on cr.number = isNull(cd.parent_id, c.parent_id)
 where YEAR(pd.datestop) = 9999;
```

i want to make **pd.name** DISTINCT because without it i have results like

```
33000000274479  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21010   1
33000000274479  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21010   1
33000000274479  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21010   2
33000000274479  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21010   2
32000100440927  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21023   4
32000100440927  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21023   4
32000100440927  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21023   5
32000100440927  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21023   5
```

but i need this variant

```
33000000274479  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21010   1
33000000274479  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21010   2
32000100440927  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21023   4
32000100440927  600000002   500000000   1008302400458   21023   5
```

help please, i need the most simple solution, without any CTE's and ect...
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group by` for all the columns in your select statement.

```
 select pd.postFilial as postoffice,
        cr.number as region,
        coalesce(cd.number, cr.number) as district,
        c.number as city,
        pd.postIndex as postcode,
        pd.name as name,
        lf.reason as lock_reason
 from pn_district pd
 inner join cd_city c on c.NUMBER = pd.cityDistrict
 left join pn_lockfilial lf with (nolock) on lf.id_postfilial = pd.postFilial
 left join cd_region cd  on cd.number = c.parent_id
 left join cd_region cr on cr.number = isNull(cd.parent_id, c.parent_id)
 where YEAR(pd.datestop) = 9999
 group by pd.name, pd.postFilial, cr.number, coalesce(cd.number, cr.number), c.number, pd.postIndex, lf.reason
 ;
```

Comment: Column 'pn_district.postfilial' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause!!! and this mistake would be with every column

Comment: in 6 minutes exactly))

Answer (score 0):

You could group by all the columns that you select, or use DISTINCT:

```
 select DISTINCT
        pd.postFilial as postoffice,
        cr.number as region,
        coalesce(cd.number, cr.number) as district,
        c.number as city,
        pd.postIndex as postcode,
        pd.name as name,
        lf.reason as lock_reason
 from pn_district pd
 inner join cd_city c on c.NUMBER = pd.cityDistrict
 left join pn_lockfilial lf with (nolock) on lf.id_postfilial = pd.postFilial
 left join cd_region cd  on cd.number = c.parent_id
 left join cd_region cr on cr.number = isNull(cd.parent_id, c.parent_id)
 where YEAR(pd.datestop) = 9999
```